# Possible to return element ID in array.from?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use Array.from to cycle through values and then return the ID of that specific element? Like my code below:

```
var inputfields = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
inputfields.forEach(field => field.addEventListener('input', setTextValue));
function setTextValue() {
   textValue = Array.from(inputfields).map(e => e !== '' ? e.value : null).filter(Boolean).join(", ");
   showValues();
}
```

I'm hoping my function setTextValue can cycle through the values of `e` and then return the ID of this element instead of the value.

Comment: please share html

Comment: why does `setTextValue` use the whole `inputfields` it should have an `event` parameter where you can extract the target html input field.

Comment: hmm I think you're right @Onheiron, do you know how to add this in this case?

Comment: @Sybrentjuh sure, you just need to add an `event` parameter to your function like this `function setTextValue(event)` the parameter is already passed by the event listener. Finally `event.target` is your field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
var inputfields = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
inputfields.forEach(field => field.addEventListener('input', setTextValue));
function setTextValue() {
   textValue = Array.from(inputfields)
    .filter(e => !!e.value) // Remove the elements without values
    .map(e => e.id) // Get the id for each element
    .join(", "); // comma separated ids

   showValues();
}
```

Comment: Hmm I just tested this and the issue is that it now checks if the element has an ID and then adds the ID to textvalue. The problem is, all element have an ID. So no matter which element I type in, it adds all the ID's to textValue.

Comment: Ahh, so you just want the textValue to equal the id of the current element only?

Comment: I've updated the code, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Well kind of haha. Inputfields has multiple 3 input[type=text] elements, so what I wanted is to add the ID to textValue only if the value of that element isn't empty. But it might be easier to just write 3 different functions for each element

Comment: So initially, if the value of this element is empty, add the ID to textValue ( and this for each element). So if 3 input values are filled in, textValue would be like: ID1, ID2, ID3. And if only one is filled in it only shows that element.

Comment: "And if only one is filled in it only shows that element" you mean "that element's id", right?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant, tested and works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)